# Universal App (WP & WinRT) should i use Cirrious MvvmCross or Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, mvvmcross

I would like your input, so that i can make a good decision on whether I should use Cirrious MvvmCross or Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit?

I am going to be developing 2 applications using Universal Apps (Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1) in XAML/C#.  I am not new to developing windows phone and windows 8 apps however i am new to developing MVVM apps and thus would greatly appreciate you into in this?

Should i use Cirrious MvvmCross or Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit, (should I use something else) what are their strengths and weakness? 
Thank you for your time and your help!

Comment: I'm not sure MvvmCross fully supports universal apps yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvvmLight does not have support for iOS yet. Support for Android was added in version 4.0 in May 2014. More info here : http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/05/mvvm-light-v4-4-with-xamarin-android-support/

MvvmCross does not support Universal Apps (yet).
More info here :https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/656
A ray of hope here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week05jun14/mvvmcross-support-for-universal-apps

Looks like you have two options -

1. MvvmCross allows you to share code with Windows Phone and Windows 8 also. Just not via Universal App project. If the objective is to share code - you can go with MvvmCross. You wil get your WinPhone and WinStore apps along with Android and iOS also.
2. Start with Mvvmlight on Universal App and hope for Xamarin.iOS support soon.
   http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/04/building-a-universal-application-for-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-8-1-with-mvvm-light/

Answer (score 2):

Is there an added benefit for using MVVMCross in your app? Will you be developing an Android or IOS APP? If the answer no, then there is no need for MVVMCross or such. The new WinRT API should have 95% of what your app needs. You can add a portable class library to the solution and share third party libraries between the apps as well.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross is the best way to cross-platform work with xamarin for exemple but you can work with it just for create windows and windows phone app.
MvvmLight is really good to implement mvvm pattern in your project.

Just for create ms app, you should work with mvvm light.